# Javascript onclick Event not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below are the following simple codes. When I click on the button, the javascript function myFunction is called and the variable str is set to the string test. Then finally, the value stored in variable str is set to the text field where the id attribute is equal to demo and displays this string in the text field.

However, in practice, nothing happens when I click on the Click Me button. You can try it in your browser. Could someone please tell me how to modify the codes so that the text 'test' appears in the text field when the button Click Me is clicked.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction(str)
{
$('#demo').val(str);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Testing...</p>

<button onclick="myFunction("test")">Click me</button>

<input type="text" id="demo" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: implementation of myFunction ? How do it ?

Comment: try to write "test" in single quotes

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction('test')">Click me</button>

Answer (score 3):

change to this:

```
onclick='myFunction("test")'
```

and do this too:

```
function myFunction(str) {
    document.getElementById('demo').value = str;
}
```

with `.querySelectorAll()`

```
document.querySelectorAll('#demo').value = str;
```

---

You have a bad implementation of double quotes like that either you wrap that up with single quote or escape the inner ones.

### Note:

You have not used jQuery library so still this won't work as you intended so you can choose to load jQuery library too or go with the native javascript.

---

Better to go unobtrusive:

First do this:

```
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

then this script:

```
function myFunction(str) {
    document.getElementById('demo').value = str;
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
    myFunction('test');
};
```

Comment: I like your style ;) no jQuery. but if you are going down that road why still use the inline listener?

Comment: @rlemon was updating that one.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes error!

Change

```
<button onclick="myFunction("test")">Click me</button>
```

To

```
<button onclick="myFunction('test')">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out you need to use single quotes, however you've also referenced `$` as a function, but don't appear to have included any additional libraries.

Assuming you're using jQuery this should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction(str)
{
$('#demo').val(str);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Testing...</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('test')">Click me</button>

<input type="text" id="demo" />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

Need change `""` on `''`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myFunction(str) {
            $('#demo').val(str);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Testing...</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('test')">Click me</button>

<input type="text" id="demo"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how `$` is going to work if you don't have jQuery loaded. BTW i am not the DV.

Comment: Ok, i'm corrected. But question does not include a jquery link too.

Answer (score 0):

Two things in you code. `$('#demo').val(str);` is a jquery & u didnt add jquery library. & `<button onclick="myFunction("test")">Click me</button>` is error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction(str)
{
document.getElementById("friendName").value=str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Testing...</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('test');">Click me</button>

<input type="text" id="demo" />


</body>
</html>
```